# Count para dos tablas, para una estadística

Tags: group-by

tengo esta consulta, funciona para lo que necesito, pero necesito que tome en cuenta el stock, solo hace la cuenta de la cantidad de libros por salas

```
SELECT 
  s.sala, 
  COUNT(l.IdSalas) as total 
FROM Libros l, Salas s 
WHERE l.IdSalas = s.IdSalas 
GROUP BY l.IdSalas;
```

solo muestra la cantidad por sala en la gráfica.

estaba intentando con unos INNER JOIN pero nada

el que me pueda ayudar se lo agradesco

Comment: Hola, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so] por favor termina el [tour] para que conozcas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtengas tu primera medalla 

Comment: Envíanos las tablas Libros y Salsas para localizar el stock que quieres tener en cuenta. En INNER JOIN hará lo mismo que con el producto cartesiano que planteas, pero de forma más eficiente, no tendrá en cuenta el stock que comentas.